# App Engine alternative for PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, cloud, paas

Does anyone know of a company that allows us to deploy PHP/MySQL applications on their cloud platform similar to Google App Engine? We would like the platform to be user-friendly as well as autoscale without intervention.

1. I don't want to SSH into every server in order to update the servers.
2. We need a MySQL database that autoscales, auto-shards, and automatically replicates.
3. Auto firewall configuration for the newly-created instances or existing servers.

Comment: include "platform as a service" or "paas" in your google searches

Comment: added as favorite, cause a long time I'm looking for a platform like this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution that fit my criteria is **Scalr** . This is the ultimate PaaS solution out there. Auto mysql scaling, auto app scaling, you can create roles that apply to all servers without ssh ing into every single server.

Answer (score 6):

One alternative for PHP based (cloud) apps is [PHP Fog](https://phpfog.com/). It also appears to have the MySQL capability you need.

Since this service is essentially a *cloud* hosted service, you won't need to deal with the underlying layers so it takes care of your firewall configuration and similar requirements.

Answer (score 3):

recently i saw an article about pagodabox
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/elevate-your-php-to-the-cloud
http://pagodabox.com/

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your needs, you could consider using App Engine with [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) (currently in limited preview) in conjunction with [Quercus PHP](http://quercus.caucho.com/), a Java implementation of PHP that runs on App Engine.

Comment: Ick, a Java implementation of PHP? The poor soul who came up with that idea must have been either under duress or under the influence.

Comment: Do you have evidence for this being bad? Sounds like an interesting idea to me.

Comment: you are right man, one of the problem that I face in computer world is that everyone that knows a little becomes an expert...